# Mysql JOIN one table with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

`ADS`: id, text, **number**

`TABLE2`: id, user_id, **number**
`TABLE3`: id, user_id, **number**
`TABLE4`: id, user_id, **number**

user_id isn't unique. Can exist or not.

Output I'd like to have:
If **number**   of `ADS` table is equal to **number**   of `TABLE1` OR `TABLE2` OR `TABLE3`, display text - only ones.

I've tried:

```
SELECT ADS.text FROM ADS 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.user_id = ? 
WHERE ADS.number = TABLE2.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE3.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE4.number 
GROUP BY ADS.id
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
ADS.text FROM ADS 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.user_id = ? 
WHERE ADS.number = TABLE2.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE3.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE4.number 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
ADS.text FROM ADS 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.user_id = ? 
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.user_id = ? 
WHERE ADS.number = TABLE2.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE3.number OR 
ADS.number = TABLE4.number 
) request 
ORDER BY ADS.id

$reponse->execute(array($_SESSION['id'],$_SESSION['id'],$_SESSION['id']));
```

I always have too much or not enough output...

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT ADS.text
FROM ADS a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 t WHERE t.user_id = ? AND t.number = a.number) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 t WHERE t.user_id = ? AND t.number = a.number) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE4 t WHERE t.user_id = ? AND t.number = a.number);
```